# How to put an input text into a yii2 kartik gridview and pass params from the view to controller?

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have tried with this code but not appear to be ok, no parm recieved with GET.

The idea is put an input box for the quantity (attribute cantidad) and then pass this quantity when user press the view button (it's the view function that I customized)

View code:

```
<?php

Html::beginForm(Url::toRoute(["customers/addproduct", 'id'=>$searchModel->id]), "POST");

$dataProvider->pagination = [
    'pagesize' => 10,
];

echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'summary' => "Mostrando {begin} - {end} de {totalCount} productos",
    'containerOptions' => ['style' => 'overflow: auto'],
    'headerRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
    'filterRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
    'pjax' => false,
    'columns' => [
        ['class'=>'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
        [
            'label' => 'Imagen',
            'attribute' => 'id_image',
            'vAlign' => 'middle',
            'format' => 'image',
            'value' => function($searchModel) {
                return 'http://prestashop.xxxxxx.xxx:1100/'.$searchModel->id_image.'-home/'.$searchModel->link_rewrite.'.jpg';
            },
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'EAN',
            'attribute'=>'ean13',
            'vAlign'=>'left',
            'pageSummary'=>'Total',
        ],
        [
            'attribute'=>'producto',
            'vAlign'=>'left',
            'pageSummary'=>'Total',
        ],
        'categoria',
        'atributos',
        [
            'header' => 'Cantidad',
            'attribute'=>'cantidad',
            'vAlign'=>'middle',
            'hAlign'=>'right',
            'value' => function($searchModel){
                return Html::textInput('quantity'.$searchModel->id, $searchModel->cantidad, ['value'=>'quantity', 'maxlength'=>10,'style'=>'width:80px']);
            },
            'format' => 'raw',
        ],
        [
            'label' => 'Precio',
            'attribute' => 'precio',
            'vAlign' => 'middle',
            'hAlign' => 'right',
            'format' => ['decimal', 2],
        ],
        [
            'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{view}',
            'dropdown' => false,
            'vAlign' => 'middle',
            'buttons' => [
                'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return Html::a('Añadir Producto', $url, [
                        'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Añadir'),
                        'type' => 'submit',
                    ]);
                }
            ],
            'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
                if ($action === 'view') {
                    $url = 'index.php?r=customers/shopping&act=v&id='.$model->id.'&c='.$model->id_customer;
                    return $url;
                }
            }
        ],
    ],
    // set export properties
    'export' => [
        'fontAwesome' => true,
    ],
    'bordered' => false,
    'striped' => false,
    'condensed' => true,
    'responsive' => true,
    'hover' => true,
    'showPageSummary' => true,
    'showFooter' => false,
    'floatHeader' => true,
    'floatHeaderOptions' => ['scrollingTop' => '50'],
    'pjax' => false,
    'panel' => [
        'type' => GridView::TYPE_SUCCESS,
        'heading' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i> Productos',
        'footer' => '',
        'after' => false,
    ],
    'persistResize' => false,
]);

Html::endForm()
```

Controller Code

```
if (Yii::$app->request->get())
{
    if (isset($_GET['c']))
    {
        $id_unique = Html::encode($_GET["id"]);
        $quantity = Html::encode($_POST['quantity'.$id_unique]);
        $id_customer = Html::encode($_GET["c"]);
        ($quantity > 0) ? $d = 1 : $d = 2;
        $this->addProduct($idshop, $id_customer);
    }
    elseif (isset($_GET['shoppingcart']))
    {
        $id_supplier = Html::encode($_GET["shoppingcart"]);
        //return Yii::$app->response->redirect(Url::to(["shoppings/vieworder"]));
    }
    elseif (isset($_GET['bootbox']))
    {
        $id_supplier = Html::encode($_GET["checkout"]);
        //$this->launchModalDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        $id_supplier = $user->id_supplier;
    }
}
else
{
    $searchModel = new TablaNsCustomerProductSearch;
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->searchCustomer(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('shopping/shopping', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);                   
}

$searchModel = new TablaNsCustomerProductSearch;
$dataProvider = $searchModel->searchCustomer(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

return $this->render('shopping/shopping', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Cannot understand the ` if (isset($_GET['c']))` part of your code. Where is that `c` defined? Can you `var_dump(Yii::$app->request->post())` ?

Comment: c is my id_customer defined in urlCreator: $url = 'index.php?r=customers/shopping&act=v&id='.$model->id.'&c='.$model->id_customer;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i do some modification to your code, maybe you need to do more because i don't know how you are implementing this, but here it is:

the view:

```
Html::beginForm(Url::toRoute(["customers/addproduct",'id'=>$searchModel->id]), "POST");

$dataProvider->pagination = [
    'pagesize' => 10,
];

echo GridView::widget([
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'filterModel' => $searchModel,
'summary' => "Mostrando {begin} - {end} de {totalCount} productos",
'containerOptions' => ['style' => 'overflow: auto'],
'headerRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
'filterRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
'pjax' => false,
'columns' => [
    ['class'=>'kartik\grid\SerialColumn'],
    [
        'label' => 'Imagen',
        'attribute' => 'id_image',
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        'format' => 'image',
        'value' => function($searchModel) {
            return 'http://prestashop.xxxxxx.xxx:1100/'.$searchModel->id_image.'-home/'.$searchModel->link_rewrite.'.jpg';
        },
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'EAN',
        'attribute'=>'ean13',
        'vAlign'=>'left',
        'pageSummary'=>'Total',
    ],
    [
        'attribute'=>'producto',
        'vAlign'=>'left',
        'pageSummary'=>'Total',
    ],
    'categoria',
    'atributos',
    [
        'header' => 'Cantidad',
        'attribute'=>'cantidad',
        'vAlign'=>'middle',
        'hAlign'=>'right',
        'value' => function($searchModel){
            return Html::textInput('quantity'.$searchModel->id, $searchModel->cantidad, ['id'=>"quantity.$searchModel->id",'value'=>'quantity', 'maxlength'=>10,'style'=>'width:80px']);
        },
        'format' => 'raw',
    ],
    [
        'label' => 'Precio',
        'attribute' => 'precio',
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        'hAlign' => 'right',
        'format' => ['decimal', 2],
    ],
    [
        'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
        'template' => '{view}',
        'dropdown' => false,
        'vAlign' => 'middle',
        'buttons' => [
            'view' => function ($url, $model) {
                return Html::a('Añadir Producto', '#', [
                    'onclick'=>"view($model->id,'$url')",
                    'title' => Yii::t('app', 'Añadir'),
                    'type' => 'submit',
                ]);
            }
        ],
        'urlCreator' => function ($action, $model, $key, $index) {
            if ($action === 'view') {
                $url = 'index.php?r=customers/shopping&act=v&id='.$model->id.'&c='.$model->id_customer;
                return $url;
            }
        }
    ],
],
// set export properties
'export' => [
    'fontAwesome' => true,
],
'bordered' => false,
'striped' => false,
'condensed' => true,
'responsive' => true,
'hover' => true,
'showPageSummary' => true,
'showFooter' => false,
'floatHeader' => true,
'floatHeaderOptions' => ['scrollingTop' => '50'],
'pjax' => false,
'panel' => [
    'type' => GridView::TYPE_SUCCESS,
    'heading' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i> Productos',
    'footer' => '',
    'after' => false,
],
'persistResize' => false,
]);

Html::endForm()

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
function view(id,url){
    c = $('#quantity'+id).val();
    url = url+'&quantity='+c;
    window.location=url;
    return false; 
}
</script>
```

and this is the modified controler:

```
if (Yii::$app->request->get())
{
if (isset($_GET['c']))
{
    $id_unique = Html::encode($_GET["id"]);
    $quantity = Html::encode($_POST['quantity']);
    $id_customer = Html::encode($_GET["c"]);
    ($quantity > 0) ? $d = 1 : $d = 2;
    $this->addProduct($idshop, $id_customer);
}
elseif (isset($_GET['shoppingcart']))
{
    $id_supplier = Html::encode($_GET["shoppingcart"]);
    //return Yii::$app->response->redirect(Url::to(["shoppings/vieworder"]));
}
elseif (isset($_GET['bootbox']))
{
    $id_supplier = Html::encode($_GET["checkout"]);
    //$this->launchModalDialog();
}
else
{
    $id_supplier = $user->id_supplier;
}
}
else
    {
$searchModel = new TablaNsCustomerProductSearch;
$dataProvider =    $searchModel->searchCustomer(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

return $this->render('shopping/shopping', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);                   
}

$searchModel = new TablaNsCustomerProductSearch;
$dataProvider =   $searchModel->searchCustomer(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

return $this->render('shopping/shopping', [
    'searchModel' => $searchModel,
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
]);
```

i can't test this but i think it should work.

Comment: Thank you a lot @Yordankis. Very useful code, i need to do some implementations but now is 100% working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The [HTML a tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp) has a type option, but it has nothing to do with the submitting of the form.
Use `Html::button(..., ['type' => 'submit'])`, or `Html::submitInput()`

Of course the value of "cantidad" will be in $POST['quantity'.$id].